# gitlab runner has no Internet connection

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Gitlab 15.1 deployed on EKS. The gitlab runner is also deployed on the same EKS using Helm. The configuration of the runner is as follow:

```
runners:
  config: |
    [[runners]]
      executor = "kubernetes"
      [runners.kubernetes]
        namespace = "{{.Release.Namespace}}"
        image = "ubuntu:16.04"
        [[runners.kubernetes.volumes.host_path]]
          name = "daemon"
          mount_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
          read_only = true
          host_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
```

The runner by default uses image `registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner:alpine-v15.1.0`. I also use Gitlab Agent to connect to EKS. Both Gitlab runner and Gitlab agent connect to Gitlab successfully.

Mostly, the Gitlab CI/CD runner itself has Internet connection as I can `docker login` to private registry. However, the `docker build` commands in the `.gitlab-ci.yaml` fails due to lack of Internet connection. To find the cause, I run `ifconfig` in the **Dockerfile**, which only returns **lo** interface.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a problem of `docker build`. It happens in AWS Linux. Add `--network=host` solves the problem.